# My website doesn't load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code, I can't seem to load any jQuery commands. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Blank</title>
        <center>
            >
            <h1>Blank<h1>
        </center>

        <!-- put jquery at end! -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
    </body>     
</html>
```

Comment: Swap the order of the script tags, your script file has to come after jQuery

Comment: `center` tag is deprecated and removed from the Web standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made two mistakes:

- You put the link to the jQuery library inside the `type` attribute, instead of the `src`
- You are trying to load the scripts that make use of jQuery before jQuery itself

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/jQuery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it! Sorry to all didn't realise I could post this sort of thing, my regards.

Answer (score 0):

Add the library first and then insert your js file.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the source of jquery.

use like below:

```
<script src="js/app/jQuery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```